# Falcor returning un-wanted atoms?

Tags: falcor, falcor-router

I'm doing some experimentation with Falcor (falcor-router), and wondering why it sometimes returns 'atom' values.

For example I'm asking for this path: `['items',{from: 0, to: 100},['name', 'value']]`

Only 50 items exist for this path, so the only paths `items.0..50` are populated.

The resulting jsonGraph contains the correct values for `items.0..50`, but also contains values for `items.51..100` that look like this:

`51: {
  name: {
    type: "$atom"
  },
  value: {
    type: "$atom"
  }
}`

I would expected that `items.51..100` would not be present in the jsonGraph instead of being populated with these `atom` values.

Why is this happening and what can I do to avoid it?

Comment: By reading the source code and issues of the router I can tell that the behavior is on purpose. However I don't know the reasoning behing it. I have posted an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/Netflix/falcor-router/issues/189

Answer (score 1):

Presently routes which produce no data are materialized to empty atoms so the client knows that those values truly are undefined (as opposed just not cached yet).

The JSONGraph merge needs to handle the case that the response may be only a subset of the paths that were requested. If you request for three paths, but the JSONGraph response only has data for two of the paths, the JSONGraph merge knows that there's still one left, and retries the request (but only for the missing path). This process is repeated until we've hit our retry limit, or we've received data for all the paths requested.

So materializing is our way of letting the cache know that it shouldn't build missing paths and re-request for this data.

I believe we have a plan to move away from materializing soon, and only communicate the paths for which no data was returned.

https://github.com/Netflix/falcor-router/issues/189#issuecomment-247722403